# How to work with higher rank types

Tags: haskell

Playing with the church numerals. I run into the situation I can't guide the GHC type-checker around higher order types.

First I wrote an version, without any type signatures:

```
module ChurchStripped where

zero z _ = z
inc n z s = s (n z s)
natInteger n = n 0 (1+)

add a b = a b inc

{-
*ChurchStripped> natInteger $ add (inc $ inc zero) (inc $ inc $ inc zero)
5
-}

mult a b = a zero (add b)

{-
*ChurchStripped> natInteger $ mult (inc $ inc zero) (inc $ inc $ inc zero)
6
-}
```

The inferred type of `mult` is horrible, so I tried to clean-up the types with a type definitions:

```
module Church where

type Nat a = a -> (a -> a) -> a

zero :: Nat a
zero z _ = z

inc :: Nat a -> Nat a
inc n z s = s (n z s)

natInteger :: Nat Integer -> Integer
natInteger n = n 0 (1+)

{- `add :: Nat a -> Nat a -> Nat a` doesn't work, and working signature looks already suspicious -}

add :: Nat (Nat a) -> Nat a -> Nat a
add a b = a b inc

{-
*Church> natInteger $ add (inc $ inc zero) (inc $ inc $ inc zero)
5
-}

mult :: Nat (Nat a) -> Nat (Nat a) -> Nat a
mult a b = a zero (add b)

{-
*Church> natInteger $ mult (inc $ inc zero) (inc $ inc $ inc zero)
6
-}
```

It works, but the types aren't as clean as they could be. Following the [System F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) definitions I tried:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module SystemF where

type Nat = forall a. a -> (a -> a) -> a

zero :: Nat
zero z _ = z

inc :: Nat -> Nat
inc n z s = s (n z s)

natInteger :: Nat -> Integer
natInteger n = n 0 (1+)

{- This doesn't work anymore

add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add a b = a b inc

   Couldn't match type `forall a1. a1 -> (a1 -> a1) -> a1'
                 with `a -> (a -> a) -> a'
   Expected type: (a -> (a -> a) -> a) -> a -> (a -> a) -> a
     Actual type: Nat -> a -> (a -> a) -> a
   In the second argument of `a', namely `inc'
   In the expression: a b inc
   In an equation for `add': add a b = a b inc

-}
```

I guess it should be possible to write `add` with `Nat -> Nat -> Nat` type signature, but I have no idea how.

P.S. actually I started from the bottom, but it maybe easier to present this problem this way.

Comment: The forall introduces higher ranked types, and this is surely not what you want here.

Comment: @Ingo I don't see why not

Comment: To put it differently: every `Nat` you mention in your type will have its own `a` type variable, that cannot be unified with any other type variable in your signatur, but apparently, wehn you write `Nat -> Nat` you want the `a`s be the same.

Comment: @Ingo, no, really want it to stay universal. It's a bit like `id id` case (which isn't that interesting, but works). https://gist.github.com/phadej/8540770

Comment: Perhaps you want to define the type as `(a->a)->(a->a)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand `RankNTypes` well enough to tell why your original example doesn't work, but if you pack Nat into a data type, then it works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module SystemF where

data Nat = Nat (forall a. (a -> (a -> a) -> a))

zero :: Nat
zero = Nat const

inc :: Nat -> Nat
inc (Nat n) = Nat $ \z s -> s $ n z s

natInteger :: Nat -> Integer
natInteger (Nat n) = n 0 (1+)

add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add (Nat a) b = a b inc
```

Now the `Nat` type is a real data type, which helps the type checker, because it doesn't have to deal with the polymorphic type all the time, only when you actually "unpack" it.

Comment: Nice. I'd still like to know why the original example doesn't work, is it' because `forall` is moved around, if not *tied* inside the data type or something else.

Comment: Seems this is the only reasonable solution at the moment, as ExplicitTypeApplication will land soonest in ghc 7.12.1 https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4466

Answer (score 5):

bennofs is right, you really want to help the typechecker along here, in particular in `add` where you need to instantiate the `a` in `forall a . a -> (a -> a) -> a` with `Nat` (ie, the same `forall a . ...` type).

One way to do that is to introduce a newtype that wraps the polymorphic type:

```
newtype Nat' = N Nat
```

Now you can go between `Nat` and `Nat'` via `N`, and back using `unN`

```
unN :: Nat' -> Nat
unN (N n) = n
```

(It's worth noting at this point that `newtype Nat' = N Nat` is a different beast from `data Nat2 = forall a . N2 (a -> (a -> a) -> a)`.  The latter requires `-XExistentialQuantification` because it says that for some particular choice of `a`, you can make a `Nat2`.  On the other hand, the former still says that if you have `a -> (a -> a) -> a` for any arbitrary `a`, then you can make a `Nat'`.  For `Nat'` you need `-XRankNTypes`, but you don't need existentials.)

Now we can also make `inc'` to increment a `Nat'`:

```
inc' :: Nat' -> Nat'
inc' (N n) = N (inc n)
```

And we're ready to add:

```
add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add n m = unN (n (N m) inc')
```

The reason this works is because now instead of trying to convince GHC to instantiate the type of `n` with a polymorphic type `∀ a . a -> (a -> a) -> a` on its own, the `N` acts as a hint.

Example:

```
> natInteger (add (inc zero) (inc zero))
2
```

Comment: The ability to instantiate a quantified type variable with a type that is itself quantified is called "impredicativity". System F (and F-omega) both have impredicativity, Haskell/GHC (by default) has not. GHC actually has some support for impredicative types (with `-XImpredicativeTypes`), but the implementation isn't very predictable, and focuses on instantiating data type parameters with polymorphic types (such as `Maybe (forall a. ...)`).

Comment: @kosmikus, you're right.  This has nothing to do with existentials.  Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: So there isn't any way to instantiate universally qualified terms in Haskell, i.e. explicitly give the type parameter? Is it always inferred by type-inference-checking engine?

Comment: @OlegGrenrus There's no specific syntax for it, only in GHC's core language. It's been proposed, though, for example here: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication Note that for monomorphic types, you can force instantiation simply by type-annotating the function, e.g. `id :: Int -> Int` instantiates `id` to type `Int`. But with your definition of `Nat` which is a polymorphic type, `id :: Nat -> Nat` will fail.

Comment: Hm.  Just eta-expanding `add` also works (ie, implement `add :: Nat -> Nat -> a -> (a -> a) -> a` as a function taking 4 arguments).  This whole `Nat'` thing seems like an unnecessary detour.  I guess the real  point is that this is all an exercise in guiding GHC to applying the HM gen and inst rules in specific places.

Comment: **Explicit type application** seems to be on GHC 7.10.1 plans list: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Status/GHC-7.10.1

Answer (score 2):

Here's my implementation of Church numerals:

```
type Nat = forall a . (a→a) → (a→a)

zero :: Nat
zero _ = id

one  :: Nat
one    = id

inc :: Nat → Nat
inc a f = f . a f

add :: Nat → Nat → Nat
add a b f = (a f) . (b f)

mul :: Nat → Nat → Nat
mul a b = a . b

nat :: Integer → Nat
nat 0 = zero
nat n = inc $ nat (n-1)

unnat :: Nat → Integer
unnat f = f (+ 1) 0
```

It is much easier to work with them flipped (function to apply N times first, its argument second). Everything just comes out, well, *naturally*.

**EDIT**: this solution is also limited, the types are not right just like in the original question and it will break down at some point.

Comment: This is nice solution for this particular case, but it still isn’t the universal solution. For example if I try to make a lists in a similar fashion: https://gist.github.com/phadej/8594017 the same problem arises (or maybe I can do some tricks there as well, but it’s not clear which). I would accept @kosmikus comment about https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication if it were an actual answer.

Comment: Hm. Apparently I've misunderstood the question. My Nat example is actually also limited, the types are not right and it will break down sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that by using `Data.Proxy` we can give a hint to GHC:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Proxy

type Nat = forall a. Proxy a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)

zero :: Nat
zero _ _ x = x

suc :: Nat -> Nat
suc n proxy s z = n proxy s (s z)

-- add = \m n f x. m f (n f x)
add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add n m proxy s z = n proxy s (m proxy s z)

-- mult = \m n f. m (n f)
mult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mult m n proxy s z = m proxy (n proxy s) z
```

And then it works!

```
λ > :t let one = suc zero in add one one 
let one = suc zero in add one one :: Proxy a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
λ > let one = suc zero in add one one Proxy (1+) 0
2

λ > :t let two = suc (suc zero) in mult two two
let two = suc (suc zero) in mult two two
  :: Proxy a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
λ > let two = suc (suc zero) in mult two two Proxy (1+) 0
4
```