# Why does the type signature look like this? (Converting Church number to Int)

Tags: haskell, types, type-signature

I'm learning Haskell and trying to write a function that convert a Church number into a Int. My code works only if I don't write a type signature.

```
type Church a = (a -> a) -> a -> a

zero :: Church a
zero s z = z

c2i :: Church a -> Int   -- This line fails
c2i x = x (+1) 0
```

I've got the right type signature of `c2i` using `:t c2i`

```
c2i :: (Num a1, Num a) => ((a -> a) -> a1 -> t) -> t
```

but I'm wondering why it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `a` in the `c2i` signature, then it has to work with *any* `a`.
In other words, `a` is chosen by the *caller* of your function.
Concretely, it has to work with

```
c2i :: Church String -> Int
-- that is
c2i :: ((String -> String) -> String -> String) -> Int
```

Since the code does not work when `a = String`, the polymorphic type is invalid.

If you do not add a type, the compiler is able to infer some type making the code work. A simpler type could be:

```
c2i :: Church Int -> Int
```

or, after enabling a few extensions,

```
c2i :: (forall a. Church a) -> Int
```

In the latter case, we are specifying that `a` is chosen by `c2i`, not by the caller. The caller instead has to pass an argument which must have a polymorphic type: i.e., it has to pass a `Church a` for all `a`, not just a `Church String`.

Alternatively, one can even declare

```
type Church = forall a . (a->a)->a->a
```

and pass around polymorphic values, only.

Comment: the `type` declaration will be painful to work with, though. Related [SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259931/how-to-work-with-higher-rank-types)